# Words and phrases related magic(like in fantasy movies&MMO games)

Tags: translation, mandarin, word, phrase

I searched through dictionaries to understand magic related words and phrases, like in MMORPG games or Fantasy books/movies. But I'm so confused how to construct a sentence and I really want to learn. I also couldn't make proper sentences the words that I looked for like 咒语, 念咒, 咒文, 魔咒, 施法, 法術... I don't know which verb should I use with them to correspond verbs "to cast", "to do", "to put"...
I'm looking for the exact words to correspond magic, charm, spell and curse. And the phrases like "to cast a spell" and "to put a spell on someone"
Also I'm trying to make sentence with the phrases;

- "To cast fire spell"/"Casting Light Spell"/"The witch casted a dark
  spell"(I want to see the usage of it with adjectives)
- "She put a    curse him"
- "He cursed him with a spell"
- "She put a spell on me"
- "She    did lightning magic"

  etc.

I really need this community's help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Chinese languages are not English. They are completely different languages. You might not find word-to-word correspondence in sentence construction. Even if you do, it sounds unnatural or unnecessary tedious.

"To cast fire spell"/"Casting Light Spell"/"The witch casted a dark spell"(I want to see the usage of it with adjectives)

```
施火咒 / 施光咒 / 巫師施暗咒
```

"She put a curse him"

```
女子向男子施惡咒
```

"He cursed him with a spell"

```
男子向另一男子施惡咒
```

"She put a spell on me"

```
女子向我施咒
```

"She did lightning magic"

```
女子施電光法術
```

Actually there are many words and ways to say the same thing. The above is just an illustration. It depends on the context. Say, what kind of action to put or cast a spell. Other than 施, it can be be 放, 下, 落, 念 etc. Or the objective to put or cast a spell / curse. Say, 咒他落地獄 (lit. curse him to fall into the hell)